# Where can I access my deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I need to add other details to it. It's not even shown on my user page (no questions asked/deleted), as if I never asked it. (Also, I lost a lot of reputation points with it despite the fact that it had only two upvotes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your deleted question [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31500/49). It's unfortunate that it doesn't show in your user profile and you don't get a notification of its deletion.

Comment: Heh, how did you find it? Just in case I'll need to find a deleted question again.

Comment: @maklen Unfortunately only moderators can see deleted questions in a user's profile.

Comment: @maklen after editing, you can also flag it for reopening to try to get answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Technically undeletion, not reopening.

Comment: "Page not found"

Comment: @MicroMachine Unless you can see deleted questions or are the original author.