# Where to find deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Even [this existing question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/where-can-i-access-my-deleted-question) doesn't give a definite answer about: If my question gets downvoted and deleted, why there are no questions in "deleted recent questions" in my profile? It displays "No deleted recent questions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have access to the [Moderator Tools](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which comes at 10k reputation, you will have to resort to that link.

Now "Deleted Recent Questions" or "Deleted Recent Answers" will only show the posts you've [created in the past 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/321725). Since all your posts are older than 60 days, there is no post shown when you click that link.

Comment: If the reason behind this is decreasing server load, then there better to be a tool to download the user's hidden history deleted post and you can only download for limited times.